# No puedo iniciar Database Engine Tuning Advisor SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Buenos días, siempre que trato de iniciar sesión me sale este error, saben como solucionarlo?

### Database Engine Tuning Advisor

Failed to open a new connection.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

In order to perform tuning you have to be a member of sysadmin fixed server role (DTAClient)

Muchas gracias, por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El usuario con el que estás intentando usar el Tuning Advisor no tiene el rol sysadmin. Conéctate a la instancia, luego ve a security, logins, doble click en el que deseas y asígnale ese rol.